# Using web.config to redirect based on domain and language parameter

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config

I have a website that is served in two languages. I have a domain name for each language, e.g. www.englishsite.com and www.frenchsite.com

The application knows to change languages based on adding this URL parameter: 
TemplateCulture=en-CA or TemplateCulture=fr-CA.

However, I am having little success with URL rewrite functionality in web.config to map the sub-domains to the specific language.

Below are the rules I am attempting to use. This isn't working for me, and I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="redirect" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^http://www.englishsite.com$" />
        </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.englishsite.com/?{R:0}TemplateCulture=en-CA" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="redirect2" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^http://www.frenchsite.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.frenchsite.com/?{R:0}TemplateCulture=fr-CA" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule> 
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to achieve:

- If user will visit homepage `http://www.englishsite.com` it should receive redirect to `http://www.englishsite.com/?TemplateCulture=en-CA&{...something...}`
- If user will visit homepage `http://www.frenchsite.com` it should receive redirect to `http://www.frenchsite.com/?TemplateCulture=fr-CA&{...something...}`

Then you rules should be like that:

```
<rule name="redirect" enabled="true">
  <match url="^$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"  pattern="^www.englishsite.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.englishsite.com/?TemplateCulture=en-CA" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="redirect2" enabled="true">
  <match url="^$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.frenchsite.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.frenchsite.com/?TemplateCulture=fr-CA" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

**Explanation of rules above:**

- `<match url="^$" />` will match only for homepage
- `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}"  pattern="^www.englishsite.com$" />` will create condition when domain name `www.englishsite.com`
- `<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.frenchsite.com/?TemplateCulture=fr-CA" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />` will make redirect with culture specific querystring. I removed {R:0} because IIS URL rewrite module will append it automatically because you set `appendQueryString="true"`